# Alignment of textPath in SVG for a pie graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to make a pie chart using SVG. The chart comes out fine but I am not able to add a text(values in pie) to it. Tried using textpath but the aligment is an issue. I do not want to use a library because my use case has several of these simple pie on a single screen.

Please find the svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<g transform="rotate(-90 50 50)"><path d="M 50,50 l 49,0 a49,49 0 0,0 -18.010176595826515,-37.95564312955508 z" fill="#c3fcb4" id="textPath0"></path><path d="M 50,50 l 30.989823404173485,-37.95564312955508 a49,49 0 1,0 18.010176595826515,37.95564312955509 z" fill="#ffb7b3" id="textPath1"></path></g><text><textPath href="#textPath0">11</textPath></text><text><textPath href="#textPath1">67</textPath></text></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved your code and make it a little bit easier so that you can add more percentage ratio to `Svg pie chart`

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c3fcb4; 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
svg text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-size:5px;
}
 
circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 32;
  r: 16;
  cx: 16;
  cy: 16;
}
 
circle.first {
  stroke: #ffb7b3;
 
}
 le.second {
  stroke: #ffeb3b;
}
  
circle.third {
  stroke: purple;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <circle class='second' stroke-dasharray="36 100"></circle>
  <circle class='first' stroke-dasharray="86 100"></circle>
  <text x="10" y="-24" fill="#000">11</text>
  <text x="5" y="-11" fill="#000">67</text>
</svg>
```